# Why is find next in zend/eclipse Ctrl-K and not F3

Tags: eclipse, search, find, zend-studio

Is there a specific reason for it, or just a new key. Does the K for that reason have any meaning?

Comment: You can edit your question to include your previous comment (which is actually the question you intend, otherwise you're just complaining)

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure this is programming related. If anything, this maybe belongs on SU (if you phrase it like "What does the K stand for?")...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDT and other plugins, <kbd>F3</kbd> is for "Open declaration", but you could re-assign it  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> without problem.
That leaves <kbd>F3</kbd> opened to be assigned to the "Find Next" command.

Mac users have been [asking the same question](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=56819), since they are used to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.